# Does a quasi linear function has global maxima or minima

Tags: convex-optimization

I am trying to optimize a single fractional function given as `b+mx/c-mx`. I consulted some references about its convexity, the function is a quasi linear function but I am not sure whether it has same properties as of a convex function i.e a global minima or maxima. I would appreciate any  helpful comment or reference.

Comment: You may be better off asking this at math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will have maxima and minima at plus and minus infinity respectively without any restrictions on your problem since you will have a vertical asymptote at c/m (assuming you don't have a degenerate case such as m=0)